# synchronous jquery cors post fails on IE9

Tags: jquery, ajax

This works on Firefox and Chrome but not on IE9:

```
          $.ajax({
            async: false,
            url: settings['server'],
            type: "POST",
            data: "u=" + window.location
                + "&h=" + encodeURIComponent(myhtml),
            success:  function (args) { 
                myhtml = evalt(args);
            },
            error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
               alert(errorThrown);
            }
          });
```

I have set the headers in PHP, tried out the "XDR"-patch and other research on the web...

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What parameters does the error callback get?

Comment: The [`error` function](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax) is called with arguments that would probably help you debug this.

Comment: Check the console for errors

Comment: Thanks - good idea!  errorThrown says "No Transport" - I have no idea, what that means?

Comment: After inserting $.support.cors = true at the top, the error changes to "Access denied"

Comment: Solved by installing IE10 ;-)

I'm happy to say, that the problem will not persist in IE10...


Thanks for your efforts and kind regards

Answer (score 0):

Solved by installing IE10 ;-)

I'm happy to say, that the problem will not persist in IE10...